# Can I get a container object from an iterator?

Tags: c++, stl, stdvector

```
std::vector<int> vec={1,2,3};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = vec.begin();

if(vec == get_vec_from_it(it)){
  puts('sucesss');
}
```

```
std::vector<int> get_vec_from_it(std::vector<int>::iterator it){
/*?*/
}
```

How should I write `get_vec_from_it` function in the above example?

Comment: No, there's no standard way to get the container (or a reference to it) from an iterator. Why do you want it anyway? What problem is that supposed to solve?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude  I'm writing a c++ program originally written in C. This program manipulates a tree structure that is implemented by a nested linked list. I replaced the linked list with std::vector in the new c++ program. The program has a function that searches a certain node in the tree and the program is supposed to iterate through the list that contains it. I made a function that returns the iterator that points to the node but I couldn't write the stop condition in a for statement. So I wonder if the stop condition can be written like `it!=get_vec_from_it(it).end()`.

Comment: Workaround: `const auto end_it = vec.end();`, and then pass `end_it` along whenever you pass `it` to a function. Please note that a `vec.push_back(...)` and other method calls invalidate all your iterators (i.e. make them useless).

Comment: The fact that your original "nested linked list" structure supports a means of working back from a node to the containing list says it is designed to meet some set of requirements for which a `std::vector` is unsuitable.   So trying to re-implement it using a `std::vector` is misguided.

Answer (score 5):

The basic idea is that iterators abstract away where the elements come from, there might not even be a container. Afaik there is a single type of iterator that "knows" its container and that is `std::back_insert_iterator`, though thats an exception. The `container` member is only `protected` so there is even a way to get the container from a `std::back_insert_iterator`, but thats not how it is meant to be used.

You can adance the iterator to get the next element, but you wouldn't know where to stop, because at some point you'll reach the `end` of the vector and there is no way to identify it. If you pass `begin` and `end` you can create a copy of the original vector:

```
std::vector<int> get_vec_from_it(std::vector<int>::iterator begin ,std::vector<int>::iterator end){
    return {begin,end};
}
```

Though, thats just a different way to copy the vector and you need to know both `begin` and `end`.

---

> I made a function that returns the iterator that points to the node but I couldn't write the stop condition in a for statement. So I wonder if the stop condition can be written like `it!=get_vec_from_it(it).end()`

Functions that work on a range of elements typically take a pair of iterators, `first` and `last`, to know where to stop (alternatively a `first` iterator and number of elements can be used). Your idea of using `it!=get_vec_from_it(it).end()` is overcomplicating the issue. Just pass `vec.end()` to the function and use that: `it != end`.

Answer (score 2):

No.

You can create a vector from a pair of iterators, or an iterator and number of elements. Example:

```
std::vector<int>
get_vec_from_its(std::vector<int>::iterator first, std::vector<int>::iterator last){
    return std::vector<int>(first, last);
}

// ...
if(vec == get_vec_from_it(vec.begin(), vec.end())){
```

The function is of course so trivial that I would recommend instead to use the constructor directly.

Comment: This creates a new vector. It does not recover the original vector, which is what OP wants.

Comment: @RaymondChen `This creates a new vector.` Yes. This implements the `get_vec_from_its` that OP asked for (with changes to parameters).

Comment: @RaymondChen I thought the same, but note that OPs `get_vec_from_its` returns a `std::vector<int>` (not a reference), so OP was asking to get a copy (not sure if that was intentional though)